# Computing sum of specific field from array entries

Tags: arrays, bash, field

I have an array `trf`.  Would like to compute the sum of the second element in each array entry.

Example of array contents

```
trf=( "2 13 144" "3 21 256" "5 34 389" )
```

Here is the current implementation, but I do not find it robust enough.  For instance, it fails with arbitrary number of elements (but considered constant from one array element to another) in each array entry.

```
   cnt=0
   m=${#trf[@]}
   while (( cnt < m )); do
     while read -r one two three
     do
       sum+="$two"+
     done <<< $(echo ${array[$count]})
     let count=$count+1
   done

   sum+=0
   result=`echo "$sum" | /usr/bin/bc -l`
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it way too complicated. Something like

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
trf=( "2 13 144" "3 21 256" "5 34 389" )
declare -i sum=0 # Integer attribute; arithmetic evaluation happens when assigned
for (( n = 0; n < ${#trf[@]}; n++)); do
    read -r _ val _ <<<"${trf[n]}"
    sum+=$val
done
printf "%d\n" "$sum"
```

in pure `bash`, or just use `awk` (This is handy if you have floating point numbers in your real data):

```
printf "%s\n" "${trf[@]}" | awk '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }'
```

Comment: Or if you can install GNU datamash, `printf "%s\n" "${trf[@]}" | datamash -W sum 2`

Comment: I like the capability for floating point computations.

Comment: How could I modify the `awk` command so that the field number is taken from an outside variable?

Comment: @Angio `awk -v f=2 '{ sum += $f } END { print sum }'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` to print the entire array, one entry per line. On such an input, one loop (`while read`) would be sufficient. You can even skip the loop entirely using `cut` and `tr` to build the `bc` command. The `echo 0` is there so that `bc` can handle empty arrays and the trailing `+` inserted by `tr`.

```
{ printf %s\\n "${trf[@]}" | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr \\n +; echo 0; } | bc -l
```

For your examples this generates prints `68` (= 13+21+34+0).

Answer (score 0):

Try this `printf` + `awk` combo:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${trf[@]}" | awk '{print $2}{a+=$2}END{print "sum:", a}'
13
21
34
sum: 68
```

Oh, it's already suggested by Shawn. Then with loop:

```
$ for item in "${trf[@]}"; do
    echo $item
done | awk '{print $2}{a+=$2}END{print "sum:", a}'
13
21
34
sum: 68
```

Answer (score 0):

For relatively small arrays a `for/while` double loop should be ok re: performance; placing the final sum in the `$result` variable (as in OP's code):

```
result=0

for element in "${trf[@]}"
do
    while read -r a b c
    do 
        ((result+=b))
    done <<< "${element}"
done

echo "${result}"
```

This generates:

```
68
```

For larger data sets I'd probably opt for one of the `awk`-only solutions (for performance reasons).

Comment: Why you need `while` loop ? This could be done with `read -r a b c <<< "${element}"`